# Twincat3 Missing properties

Tags: twincat

I am working on a really simple project and I created a visualisation.
I tried editing the onClick action on a button but i do not have the option under InputConfiguration. The only options that I have are onMouseUP and onMouseDown.
I don't know if there is any license problem or any updates that I don't have.

Comment: Could you provide more info, for example screenshots? That could perhaps help

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the `Export` mode selected in the properties:
[image]